# netflix zuul 2 netty server example not working

Tags: rx-java, netflix-zuul, rx-netty

I am considering zuul 2 as a potential dynamic routing solution and trying to get a simple netty-based example to work.

**scenario**

1. `/apache` in the request -> proxy to www.apache.org
2. `/npr` in the request -> proxy to www.npr.org
3. no parameter in the request -> proxy to www.netflix.com

**steps**

1. assuming that *www.apache.org*, *www.npr.org* and *www.netflix.com* are considered **origins**, add the following to `zuul.properties` file:

   `zuul.origins=apache=www.apache.org,npr=www.npr.org,netflix=www.netflix.com`
2. in an inbound filter, analyze the request to determine whether it has `/npr` or `/apache` ([similar to this example](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/blob/2.x/zuul-netty-sample/src/main/filters/inbound/Routing.groovy#L53)), and set the `routeVip` and endpoint filter accordingly

   ```
   if ( request.getPath() == "/apache" ) {
     context.setRouteVIP( "apache" )
   } else if ( request.getPath() == "/npr" ) {
     context.setRouteVIP( "npr" )
   } else {
     context.setRouteVIP( "netflix" )
   }

   context.setEndpoint( "endpoint.ZuulNFRequest" )
   ```
3. in the endpoint filter, use the default `NfProxyEndpoint` to proxy to the appropriate endpoint

**questions**

1. judging by the fact that when I send a request to `localhost:7001` where the sample netty server is running, I keep getting the default `hello world` response back, i am not setting this up correctly. what am I doing wrong?
2. should I be setting the `context.setRouteHost()` along with the `context.setRouteVIP()` for something like this to work? ([analogously to what zuul 1 does](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/blob/1.x/zuul-simple-webapp/src/main/groovy/filters/pre/PreDecorationFilter.groovy#L46))
3. are *www.apache.org*, *www.npr.org* and *www.netflix.com* really **origins** here? if not, what are origins?